# Get Stock Price for few Stocks at every few seconds from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, rxjs

I want to write one screen of UI in react.js

1. will show the price of the stocks
2. and it will show color [ red or green ] depending upon the comparison from previous stock price.

Is there any to get fake stream online created for study purpose which can be used to continuously get stock price for few stock. The stocks price are updated every few seconds or is there way it can be created on server side( using any programming language ) and used in javascript.

I am assuming web sockets have to be used in javascript to read the stream from server.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here, they offer a free api:
https://finnhub.io/

You can create a stream out of it in a backend service.